# MySQL create table: error 1005 errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

This fails when trying to create the EXCHANGE table:

```
CREATE TABLE BOOK
(PKACC_NO VARCHAR (20) PRIMARY KEY,
TITLE VARCHAR (50),
AUTHOR VARCHAR (50),
PUBLISHER VARCHAR (50),
EDITION INTEGER (4),
PRICE INTEGER (10));

CREATE TABLE MEMBER
(PKMEMBER_ID VARCHAR (20) PRIMARY KEY,
NAME VARCHAR (50),
TYPE VARCHAR (10),
CONTACT_NO BIGINT (10),
ADHAAR_NO BIGINT(12),
LAST_VISIT DATE );

CREATE TABLE STAFF
(PKSTAFF_ID VARCHAR (20),
NAME VARCHAR(50),
ADHAAR_NO BIGINT (12),
CONTACT_NO BIGINT(10) );

CREATE TABLE EXCHANGE 
(TRANSACTION_ID VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
FK1ACC_NO VARCHAR(20),
FK2MEMBER_ID VARCHAR (20),
FK3STAFF_ID VARCHAR(20),
DATE_OF_ISSUE DATE,
DATE_OF_RETURN DATE,
FINE INTEGER(20),
REMARKS VARCHAR(20),
CONSTRAINT FK1 FOREIGN KEY (FK1ACC_NO) REFERENCES BOOK (PKACC_NO)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT FK2 FOREIGN KEY (FK2MEMBER_ID) REFERENCES MEMBER (PKMEMBER_ID)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT FK3 FOREIGN KEY (FK3STAFF_ID) REFERENCES STAFF (PKSTAFF_ID)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

The last create statement returns:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `testdb`.`EXCHANGE` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

Comment: You show 4 statements. Which one raises the error?

Answer (score 14):

At times the best way to overcome an error within your InnoDB table is to check the InnoDB table status by using this command.
   SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;

This will enlighten you on what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Among the output of that, I found a section called "LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR". It was exactly what I was looking for. Very useful, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The problem is you've forgotten to define a primary key for the STAFF table:

```
CREATE TABLE STAFF
(PKSTAFF_ID VARCHAR (20) PRIMARY KEY,
NAME VARCHAR(50),
ADHAAR_NO BIGINT (12),
CONTACT_NO BIGINT(10) );
```

Once that's sorted out, you can create the EXCHANGE table as in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly specify `ENGINE=InnoDB` when creating a table in lower versions of of MySQL where Innodb is not the default engine.